# Mysql 5.7 Stored Procedure error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions, java-stored-procedures

I an trying to create stored procedure in following format :
DELIMITER $$

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateInsertLocation` (tableName VARCHAR(255),ts BIGINT(20),systs INT(20),lat FLOAT,lon FLOAT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE FoundCount INT;

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO FoundCount
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'DB'
    AND table_name = tableName;

    IF FoundCount = 1 THEN SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',tableName,'
        (timestamp, lattitude, longitude,systime) 
    VALUES
        (','ts','lat','lon','systs')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
    EXECUTE stmt;

ELSE 
    SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `',tableName,'`(
        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
        `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
        `lattitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
        `longitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `systime` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
        KEY `LocIdx` (`vtuId`,`timestamp`),
        KEY `SysIdx` (`vtuId`,`systime`), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)'); 
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
    EXECUTE stmt;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',tableName,'
            (timestamp, lattitude, longitude,systime) 
        VALUES
            (','ts','lat','lon','systs')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql2; 
        EXECUTE stmt;

END 
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

-- When I am trying to execute this query in Mysql 5.7 I am getting following error

```
  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
  manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
  syntax to use near '');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
     EXECUTE stmt;

   ELSE SET @sql = CONCAT' at line 10
```

Can anyone help to improve this sotred procedure ?

Comment: Your single quote is not closed properly (','ts','lat','lon','systs',')');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Pay attention to order of single quotes as it can get tricky.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateInsertLocation` (tableName VARCHAR(255),ts BIGINT(20),systs INT(20),lat FLOAT,lon FLOAT)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE FoundCount INT;

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO FoundCount
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'DB'
    AND table_name = tableName;

    IF FoundCount = 1 THEN 
        SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',tableName,' (timestamp, lattitude, longitude,systime) VALUES (',ts, ',', lat, ',', lon, ',', systs, ')' );

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
        EXECUTE stmt;

    ELSE 
        SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `',tableName,'` (
        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
        `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  
        `lattitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
        `longitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        `systime` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
        KEY `LocIdx` (`vtuId`,`timestamp`),
        KEY `SysIdx` (`vtuId`,`systime`), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id) )' ); 

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END IF;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',tableName,' (timestamp, lattitude, longitude,systime) VALUES (',ts, ',', lat , ',', lon, ',', systs, ')');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
        EXECUTE stmt;

END 
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quote (') for the concat string of your create table statement and the default values within it.

Either put the default values in double quotes ("), escape them (\') or remove them as they are all numberic types.

**Edit:** Your parameters for the insert statements are also put into quotes which looks wrong, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
create schema mine;
use mine;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateInsertLocation` (tableName VARCHAR(255),ts BIGINT(20),systs INT(20),lat FLOAT,lon FLOAT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE FoundCount INT;

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO FoundCount
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'DB'
    AND table_name = tableName;

    IF FoundCount = 1 THEN SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',tableName,'
        (timestamp, lattitude, longitude,systime) 
    VALUES
        (','ts','lat','lon','systs\')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
    EXECUTE stmt;

ELSE 
    SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',tableName,'(
        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\', 
        `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',  
        `lattitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\', 
        `longitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',
        `systime` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
        KEY `LocIdx` (`vtuId`,`timestamp`),
        KEY `SysIdx` (`vtuId`,`systime`), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)'); 
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
    EXECUTE stmt;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',tableName,'
            (timestamp, lattitude, longitude,systime) 
        VALUES
            (','ts','lat','lon','systs\')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql2; 
        EXECUTE stmt;

END if;
end
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can try above code;

Firstly you need to escape all Single quote **`'`**

And you forgot to close **ENDIF**.

Comment: Hi Sagar. We prefer technical writing here where possible, and in general we prefer answers not to contain redundant or chatty material. There's no need to add "hope this helps" or variants to your answers; you have 153 of these presently, which volunteer editors may edit out over time. If you can give them less work to do, they will appreciate it!

Comment: General advice worth bearing in mind: We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc.

Comment: Thank You, For ur suggestion and time

Answer (score -1):

In the marked comment, this code was missing a quote to complete `concat` correctly

```
$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateInsertLocation` (tableName VARCHAR(255),ts BIGINT(20),systs INT(20),lat FLOAT,lon FLOAT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE FoundCount INT;

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO FoundCount
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'DB'
    AND table_name = tableName;

    IF FoundCount = 1 THEN SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',tableName,'
        (timestamp, lattitude, longitude,systime) 
    VALUES
        (','ts','lat','lon','systs',')'); /* Error in this line */
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
    EXECUTE stmt;

ELSE 
    SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `',tableName,'`(
        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
        `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
        `lattitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
        `longitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `systime` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
        KEY `LocIdx` (`vtuId`,`timestamp`),
        KEY `SysIdx` (`vtuId`,`systime`), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)'); 
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
    EXECUTE stmt;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',tableName,'
            (timestamp, lattitude, longitude,systime) 
        VALUES
            (','ts','lat','lon','systs')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql2; 
        EXECUTE stmt;

END 
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you ! for ur suggesting and time